# Why does compile Qt BluetoothDiscoveryAgent results in a Linker Error

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to compile a little Qt project, but i get a linker error.
I want to make a small project which read Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Gatt characteristics. I have an embedded Board where the BLE works.

When I start the compiler i get theses warnings / Errors:

```
qtmain.lib(qtmain_winrt.obj):-1: Warnung: LNK4099: PDB "qtmain.pdb" wurde nicht mit "qtmain.lib(qtmain_winrt.obj)" oder an "C:\Users\Kennis\Documents\build-Bachlerorarbeit-Qt_5_11_2_for_UWP_64bit_MSVC_2017-Profile\release\qtmain.pdb" gefunden; Objekt wird verknüpft, als ob keine Debuginformationen vorhanden wären.

widget.obj:-1: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(class QObject *)" (__imp_??0QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent@@QEAA@PEAVQObject@@@Z)" referenced in function""public: __cdecl Widget::Widget(class QWidget *)" (??0Widget@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)".

widget.obj:-1: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::~QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(void)" (__imp_??1QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent@@UEAA@XZ)" referenced in function ""public: virtual void * __cdecl QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)".

widget.obj:-1: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol""public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)".

widget.obj:-1: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)".

widget.obj:-1: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""public: virtual void * __cdecl QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)".
:
```

i work on Windows 10 with Qt5.11.2 for UWP 64bit (MSVC 2017).

without the line of the init of the Discovery Agent i´m able to compile the project.

I have started Qmake and rebuild multiple times.

main.cpp :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

widget.cpp :

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

#include <QtBluetooth/QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QtBluetooth/QBluetoothDeviceInfo>


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

#include <QtBluetooth/QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QtBluetooth/QBluetoothDeviceInfo>


namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

    QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent *discoveryAgent;

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

bachelorarbeit.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-02-02T21:22:40
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Bachlerorarbeit
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact 
warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain 
version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the 
APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
        widget.h

FORMS += \
        widget.ui



# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any evidence that you've included the library containing the missing code.

Comment: *When I start the compiler i get theses warnings* -- Those are not compiler errors -- the compilation was successful.  Those errors are *linker* errors -- you are calling functions that to the linker, do not exist.  So things like this:  `QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this)` where is this function found?  That's what the linker is complaining about.

Comment: Modify your .pro file to include the bluetooth module: `QT += core gui bluetooth`. Run qmake again, then rebuild the entire project. Your linker was not able to find the symbols from the bluetooth library.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's working. It´s a long time ago i code with Qt.

Comment: @kBroeker You are welcome. Happy coding with Qt ;)